# Could an actual mono black storm (Tendril of agony) deck be viable for Legacy?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

From experienced deckbuilders, how would you approach building a budget-friendly [Tendrils of Agony](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tendrils%20of%20Agony) deck? I'm thinking of basically only swamps for the manabase, but the rest (hand disruption, tutors, etc.) is okay. Would it be more of the 0-cost creatures sac or maybe sac-lands?

Is it even possible to make a good, viable storm deck that could stay consistent even without blue cantrips?

Comment: This question should be closed because it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: Perhaps a way to make this less opinion based would be to ask if a deck like what you described has ever been played at a Legacy tournament of a high enough level that the deck was tracked.

Comment: Subjective does not mean bad. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ This question isn't asking "do you like Tendrils?" and the current answer demonstrates this: it answers *why*, providing some real justification. Let's not get so caught up in the fact that the question says "good" or that it's hard to answer without some substantial knowledge that we can't recognize that there's a real question here.

Comment: You need Lion's Eye Diamonds and infernal tutors to make the deck good. Lion eye's are too expesive. I otherwise don't see the deck being viable enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very brief answer to your last question: no.

A slightly less brief answer: the card draw and selection that blue provides, along with the additional "truly free" (it doesn't cost mana or a card) storm of Gitaxian Probe, is essential to the deck's viability, letting you find your key cards more consistently.  Also, while it wasn't mentioned, the red cards (Past in Flames and/or Empty the Warrens) allow for a viable backup plan when you can't get enough storm to consistently Tendrils for lethal.

Could you *build* a mono-black Storm deck?  Yes, at least in principle, in the same way that you could build a mono-black burn deck.  Would it be viable?  Unfortunately, not in any at least modestly competitive play environment.

Comment: as a storm player - it is definitely possible to build a mono black version of storm. will it win tournaments? no. Black has very little in the way of mana producing cards (dark/cabal ritual are basically it in terms of playable options). A mono coloured storm deck would be much more likely to be playable in red. But you don't see budget storm decks in single colors for a reason, they are too fragile.

Comment: I've played mono black versions that won on turn 1 about 15%, turn 2 30% and turn 3 about 50%. If the game went longer than that I probably lost though, and lost often when going turn 1 or 2 as well (FoW is a problem). The deck still isn't cheap though. It was essentially a "play ad nauseam and win" deck.

Comment: @Cruncher In Legacy?  What do you use for a YawgWill effect, or do you even have one?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Don't have one. You play enough 0 cost cards that can storm you after ad nauseam (memnite, and ornithopter fuel the "B, sac creature: add BBBB" card). Lotus petals, and stuff. If you can play ad nauseam on turn 1 (even if you have no mana after casting) you WILL win(assuming no FoW).

Comment: Ahhh, that's a fair point.  I should probably mention ANT in this answer for completeness' sake; the deck usually _really_ wants its cantrips, but it can certainly ostensibly play without.